# Im new to laravel and trying to run an existing laravel project, when I run npm install so much "npm WARN deprecated" message appear

Tags: laravel, gruntjs

When I run npm install, some of the deprecated dependencies are not listed in my package.json as far as I know. So I don't know which dependency to remove of change. Changed some details as my post marked as spam before this :

```
C:\laragon\www\laravel>npm install
npm WARN deprecated consolidate@0.15.1: Please upgrade to consolidate v1.0.0+ as it has been modernized with several long-awaited fixes implemented. Maintenance is supported by Forward Email at YOUR_URL_HERE ; follow/watch YOUR_URL_HERE for updates and release changelog
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: YOUR_URL_HERE
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See YOUR_URL_HERE
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see YOUR_URL_HERE
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: YOUR_URL_HERE
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See YOUR_URL_HERE
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see YOUR_URL_HERE
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See YOUR_URL_HERE for details.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read YOUR_URL_HERE to update!
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see YOUR_URL_HERE
npm WARN deprecated axios@0.19.2: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see YOUR_URL_HERE
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.

added 1522 packages, and audited 1523 packages in 1m

98 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

89 vulnerabilities (2 low, 60 moderate, 27 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

This is the package.json. Changed some details as my post marked as spam before this

```
{
    "name": "NAME_HERE",
    "author": "EMAIL_HERE",
    "private": true,
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "cross-var $npm_execpath run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-var $npm_execpath run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "cross-var $npm_execpath run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "cross-var $npm_execpath run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest",
        "tdd": "cross-var $npm_execpath run test -- --watch --notify"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.12",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.9.0",
        "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.29",
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "cross-var": "^1.1.0",
        "jest": "^24.8.0",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "pace": "github:HubSpot/pace#v1.0.2",
        "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.1",
        "sass": "^1.21.0",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "sweetalert2": "^9.3.5",
        "vue": "^2.6.10",
        "vue-jest": "^3.0.4",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "development": "last 1 version",
        "production": ">2%, Firefox ESR"
    },
    "jest": {
        "testURL": "URL_HERE",
        "roots": [
            "<rootDir>/tests/Javascript/"
        ],
        "moduleNameMapper": {
            "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/resources/js/$1"
        },
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "js",
            "vue"
        ],
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
            ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest"
        }
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=6.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "metismenu": "^3.0.6"
    }
}
```

I think this project might be using something called "grunt". Tried to change the dependencies but still doesn't work. How do I fix this?

Comment: Change your ```devDependencies``` version. some of them is outdated.

Comment: will "npm update" do it?

Comment: Yes, you can ```npm update``` But as I said already, you need to check your **devdependencies** before you do an npm update because it will not upgrade the version in your dependencies. Example here, you are using ```core-js@2.6.12``` and there is logs already that cannot be use and there is recommended version you want to use. As you can see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js)(*latest:* ```core-js@3.31.0```) you are using an obsolete one, so change the version in your dependencies then do an **npm update**